# Difference of Disjoint and Independence in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given the following definitions:

1. Disjoint means if event A occur ,B cannot possibly occur. Draw in the Venn Diagram, it should not contain any intersection. Hence, mathematically,

   P(A,B) = 0.
2. However, for independence, it says if we know that A occurs, it tells us nothing whatsoever about what B occurs. Does it mean it does have intersection?? Come to think of it. If A and B are independent,

   P(A n B) = P(A)P(B).

Mathematically speaking, if A and B are disjoint, then

```
P(AnB) = 0 /= P(A)P(B)
```

If 
    P(AnB) = P(A)P(B), 
then 
    it means there should be an intersection???

Comment: There is *always* an intersection. However, it can be empty. In that case the events are disjoint. Independence does not guarantee that the intersection is not empty. For instance if $A$ and $B$ are both empty then they are independent and have an empty intersection.

Comment: @drhab so you mean independence may also mean disjoint? But disjoint will never lead to independence?

Comment: Independence does not *mean* disjoint and disjoint does not *mean* independence. I am only saying that these concepts do not exclude eachother. You can have a situation where you have independence *and* disjointness.

Comment: Can you cite a situation that does have independence and disjointness and give an explanation why is that so?

Comment: Let it be that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and secondly that $P(A)=0$. Then also $P(A\cap B)=0=P(A)P(B)$ wich means independence by definition.

Comment: Interesting.. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @drjab Wait. If P(A) = 0, in reality, then there is no event A. Does it still mean that there is a situation where you have independence and disjointness?

Comment: p(a) = 0 means the probability of event A occuring is 0, not that the event of A doesn't exist. if you are given the conditions p(a) > 0 and p(b) > 0 then there isn't independence if disjoint